# How to apply URL Rewrite rules correctly for IIS applications

Tags: iis, seo, url-rewrite-module

We have an IIS 8.5 setup where a single website is bound to domain.com and contains a number of IIS applications accessed as domain.com/app1, domain.com/app2 etc.

Each of these applications points to the same physical path, so they all share a web.config. This is a specific CMS configuration.

I have applied the usual URL Rewrite rules (redirect to HTTPS, enforce lowercase, add trailing slash etc.) to the web.config each application shares but have realised these rules are only applied to the URL after the application name. The rules I have are just standard rules added using the URL Rewrite GUI:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Enforce lowercase" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So, for example, `http://domain.com/APP1/PATH` redirects to `https://domain.com/APP1/path/`. Also, `https://domain.com/app1` **doesn't** redirect to `https://domain.com/app1/`.

The HTTPS rule is fine, but can anyone tell me how I can configure the other 2 rules so that they work with the entire URL, bearing in mind that the specific application name (app1, app2 etc) needs to be handled generically.

**UPDATE**

I've discovered that I can enforce lowercase URLs using a global rule in IIS (at server level) which is sufficient for my needs. But it doesn't seem to be possible to replicate the website-level rule for adding/removing trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change action URL.

```
   <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't help with adding trailing slash to the root URL (e.g. https://domain.com/app1) since in that case the rule won't even run.

Comment: This is the rule I use on my websites, not sure why it would work for me and not you. Maybe you have another rule interfering with it?

Comment: I think if you test again you'll find that rule only works on the relative path, so it won't redirect domain.com to domain.com/ (or in my case domain.com/app to domain.com/app/ because app is an IIS application)